# get count of subscribers for a topic in Mosquitto

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

Is it possible to get the count of subscribers for a topic in Mosquitto? broker status seems to show only the total amount of subscribers.

Comment: It is very difficult to come up with a number for a specific topic especially when you start to include wildcard topics. One of the core tenets of Pub/Sub is to totally decouple the publisher/subscriber, so knowing how many subscribers is against that philosophy

Answer (score 0):

Manageability of the broker is the "added-value". Different brokers have
different management capabilities. I know that MessageSight includes a
WEB interface and SNMP agent to query stats, but do not know this particular 
feature.

Since mosquitto is open-source, you can add to its value by implementing this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to

```
$SYS/broker/clients/connected
```